# Null Safe Checks and if condition priorty

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Assume a scenario such as this;

```
if(event.getAdapter() != null  && event.getAdapter().getCount() > 0)
```

In the code above,  first i check if it is null then  i check if count whether above zero. If first condition is checked before second condition then this code will work as intended. But if *(i heard that jvm sometimes starts checking most failure conditions to speed up)* second condition is checked than first one then this code will give runtime error.

So my question is, is above check code safe? Will it work as intended? or *jvm may start from second condition sometimes?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entirely safe, *when* a second thread cannot change the adapter.

Java 8 might yield an `Optional<Adapter>` and allow a different formulation.

Answer (score 2):

The above code is safe. The JVM will short-circuit the second evaluation if the first is `false`.

The [JLS-15.23. Conditional-And Operator `&&`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) says (in part)

> The conditional-and operator `&&` is like `&` ([§15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use &&, all conditions will be executed from the left to the right until one of your conditions is evaluated as false.

example :

```
A && B && C
```

if B is false, C will not be evaluated.

However if you use just one &, all your conditions will be evaluated, even if one is false. It is the main difference between & and && as logical operator.

I hope it will help you.